# ModuleNotFoundError: No module after QGIS 3.36 install

Tags: qgis

After installing QGIS 3.36 using Flatpak on Ubuntu 22.04, I have several plugins that are not working. This includes these errors:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebKit' from 'PyQt5' (/app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/**init**.py)

PyQt5 is installed.
Python 3.11 is installed

Any ideas for a path forward?